# How to insert a View in a Panel?

Tags: views, panels

I want to create a page with a panel (using the [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) module). Then want to put a view in it. But I don't see anything in the content section, this is how it looks like:

[image]

I saw the question about "[How to add Views into a Panels page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49682/how-to-add-views-into-a-panels-page)", but in my Views display there is no `panel pane` display.

Where is my problem, do I need some additional module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Drupal, you had just one step more to do that, go to your module list in `admin/modules` and in `Panels` package enable `Views content panes` module then all views exists for using in panels. also it provide a news dispaly in views.

[image]

Also you can see [this video](https://drupalize.me/videos/basics-views-content-panes?p=1147) for more getting involve with views pane

Answer (score 0):

Can't add this as a comment :(  But, oh well...

`Views content panes (views_content)` is in Chaos tool suite [`Chaos tools (ctools)`] not `Panels (panels)`.

```
# drush pmi views_content
 Extension     :  views_content
 Project       :  ctools
 Type          :  module
 Title         :  Views content panes
 Description   :  Allows Views content to be used in
                  Panels, Dashboard and other modules
                  which use the
                  CTools Content API.
 Version       :  7.x-1.12
 Package       :  Chaos tool suite
 Core          :  7.x

 Files         :  plugins/views/views_content_plugin_display_ctools_context.inc,
                  plugins/views/views_content_plugin_display_panel_pane.inc,
                  plugins/views/views_content_plugin_style_ctools_context.inc
 Requires      :  ctools, views
 Required by   :  none
```